# PostgreSQL table moving avarage

Tags: postgresql, moving-average

I would like to create a moving average and store the results. I could either create a new table from the query or add a new column with the results. What would be the preferred option and if I want to create a column with the moving average, how could I accomplish that?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/871c6/4

Answer (score 1):

you can create a table with the result like this.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT year, ptotww,
   AVG (ptotww)
       OVER(ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as avg3_ptotww
       FROM ma_test
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view instead.

```
CREATE VIEW ma_test_vw AS
SELECT ma_test.*,
       SUM(ptotww)
           OVER(ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as sum_ptotww
FROM ma_test
```

However, if the data doesn't change that often, recalculating it for every time the query is run might not be optimal, so in that case you can create a materialized view instead.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ma_test_vw AS
SELECT ma_test.*,
       SUM(ptotww)
           OVER(ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as sum_ptotww
FROM ma_test;
```

And then after you have changed/added some data to the original table, you would have to do:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ma_test_vw
```

in order to make the new data visible in the view.